# Can't write HFS+ in Mac OSX

Tags: mac, leopard, hfs+

I've an external HDD of 500GB and in HFS+ format. It works normally on my Mac running OS X 10.5.8. After I plugged it into a machine running Windows, I found a vacant partition of 128MB and formatted it to NTFS. I used Paragon HFS+ for Windows to read and copy files.

Now I'm not able to write to that disk on my Mac. What is the problem?

Comment: sounds like you got a Windows partition table.  empty, reformat, copy back, don't do it again.

Comment: So what if i format the 128mb partition, will i get a Mac partition table?

Comment: Don't think so.  Only way to be certain it works correctly is to reformat the drive.